# Use BT MeetMe conferencing service under Ubuntu - Dolby plugin installation

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, sound, google-chrome, plugins

Does anybody know a solution to install the `Dolby plugin` to Google Chrome under Ubuntu (16.04) required for [BT Meetme](https://my.webjoin.com/) conferencing service?
After clicking the `Install Dolby Voice` button on [this page](https://my.webjoin.com/dolby/connectivity/), the `Download` button is not working. The reason for that must be that Google Chrome is listed as supported just under Windows and Mac systems (Firefox not supported at all). But in Google Chrome for Ubuntu extensions [Dolby Voice](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dolby-voice-13/clloobkgbdighillbfomkhjhgeempchd) and [MeetMe Dolby Voice](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meetme-dolby-voice-11/lflnplggpolkcgknahacafilopgngelc) could be found (but enabling them does not solve the problem), what makes me wonder if it is possible to utilize them somehow.

Update (2020-04-02): Although for some time both plugins are available for Chrome's Ubuntu version, the BTMeetMe still want me to download the plugin and not working. (Ubuntu 18.04, Chrome 80.0.3987.162 (Official Build) (64-bit))